# spring multi level Inner join query JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to run a query in the following way

```
  select * from (select * from table a inner join table b 
  where a.id=b.customerId) x inner join select a.x,a.y from table a  where a.sampleId=x.id
```

I need to execute the above query with jpa spring. Any examples of such kind of scenarios. I have it is easy to do with single inner  join but not multiple inner join .Can some one explain with a example. Thanks

Comment: It's impossible to answer this question since you have not show us the entity class which maps to the table named `table`. Furthermore, the SQL query itself looks extremely silly: AFAICT, there's no good reason for the use of subqueries there, and it could be written much more clearly using just joins. So I suggest starting with better-written SQL.